# DatagramSocket does not work over internet

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, datagram

I am writing an application which uses `DatagramSockets` to transfer data over the internet.
If I try int with `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` it works, on the internet it does not.

After searching the problem, I found out that there is this Address `0.0.0.0` you have to assign it to, to get it to work over the internet. So my DatagramSocket for the server is currently open the following way:

```
socket = new DatagramSocket(4713,InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"));
```

My Client is currently opened the same way with another port. But I can't receive data.

I also thought maybe I need to open the ports on my router, but it did not help.

Also, one other issue I have is, if I really need to open the `DatagramSocket` with a port given in the constructor for my client, too, how am I able to find any free udp port, as I don't want to use the same all the time.

Can someone please help me with those two issues?

What do I need to do to get UDP DatagramSockets to work over the internet?

How would I, if I need to, get random available Ports for my UDP client?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html

Comment: You are still broadcasting to yourself.  You need to send it to a public IP address.

Comment: I understood it, if I use 0.0.0.0 it would make the socket to send and receive from everywhere. And I set the address in my Datagrampacket. There I'm setting it to the ip and the port with the data.

Comment: Just to double check, when you open/forwarded the ports you did so for udp?

Comment: Yes it was for UDP Ports, still not working though. I have no idea what to do to get DatagramSockets to work over the Internet...

Comment: Don't specify the local addres at all. If you don't care about the local port, specify zero, but you *do* care about the local port if you have to arrange port forwarding, which seems to be the problem here.